# Buyin a license for windows 10 in one computer to use in another

Tags: windows-10

My mother just bought a FreeDOS laptop. I want to install Windows 10. My sister lives in the US and my mother in Argentina (this is where I live)

My sister has offered to buy aa Windows License so that I can activate my mothers laptop.

Is there any reaason why this might not work? Is it possible to do this?

Any recommended sites to buy the licence from that are not Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows 10 License remains installed in two computers, you need a volume retail license with 2 occurrences.

Windows installs (language and locale) are also different by Country.

So if you want a US install get the license from Microsoft US. If you also want an install in Argentina, get another license from Microsoft in Argentina.

If you only need one license (Argentina), still purchase it in Argentina and arrange for your sister to pay for it.

Do not buy a third party license unless from a Microsoft Partner.

Comment: The windows license will be ONLY in my mothers computer. Alsow I don't mind if my mother's computer is in english. I'd rathere prefer it. In that case is okay for mys sister to buy it? Will it work?

Comment: You are not in the country where your sister is, and so I believe you would be better to source the license in Argentina and then arrange for your sister to pay for it. That will definitely work better in the long run. I adjusted my answer to accommodate this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your time!